# Is it possible to run a report of all Lists that are marked as 'public' in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, list, search, subscription-center

I have recently started at a company that has a LOT of List and Publication List Sub-Folders in Marketing Cloud. Looking at the Subscription Center, it looks like at least some Lists have been marked as 'public' when they shouldn't be, showing internal list names to customers in the Subscription Center.

I've tried looking through the sub-folders individually for the lists that are marked as public, but with literal hundreds of sub-folders it's been impossible to find them.

Is there a way to either search for a list name within all sub-folders, or run a report of all Lists that are marked as 'public' (and preferably their sub-folder location)?

Comment: Are you open to doing a SOAP call?

Comment: To be honest that’s a bit beyond my technical ability...